# Generate an XES file from an event log in CSV format

Tags: csv, event-log

Could someone help me out on how to generate an xes file from a csv file containing event logs. I tried many websites, tutorials but failing all the time.

Because, they aren't providing adequate information. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go: [Importing CSV files using the ProM 6.5 Log package](https://svn.win.tue.nl/trac/prom/export/22567/Documentation/LogCSVImport.pdf)

You'll need the latest ProM-Version for that from www.promtools.org

Comment: Works for me, try again now.